# Filling in a MultiView ViewHolder inside a RecyclerView With Data Binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

So I was able to get to a close point in creating the MultiView ViewHolder, but I am still a bit confused with some details. First how would I fill in the RecyclerView since I have multiple data classes(in this case, manually). Second, how would the Adapter know when to show a particular view? I'll leave the code here

Data Class(es)

```
sealed class InfoRecyclerViewItems{

    class WithPicture (
        val id: Int,
        val movieName: String,
        val thoughts: String
            ): InfoRecyclerViewItems()

    class WithoutPicture(
        val id: Int,
        val movieName: String,
        val thoughts: String
    ): InfoRecyclerViewItems()

}
```

The Adapter

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(infoItems: MutableList<InfoRecyclerViewItems>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MainViewHolder>() {
    private var infoItems1: MutableList<InfoRecyclerViewItems>

    init {
        this.infoItems1 = infoItems
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainViewHolder {
        return when(viewType){
           R.layout.container_one -> MainViewHolder.WithPictureViewHolder(
               ContainerOneBinding.inflate(
                   LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
           )

           R.layout.container_two -> MainViewHolder.WithoutPictureViewHolder(
               ContainerTwoBinding.inflate(
                   LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
           )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view given")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when(holder){
            is MainViewHolder.WithPictureViewHolder -> holder.bind(infoItems1[position] as InfoRecyclerViewItems.WithPicture)
            is MainViewHolder.WithoutPictureViewHolder -> holder.bind(infoItems1[position] as InfoRecyclerViewItems.WithoutPicture)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = infoItems1.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when(infoItems1[position]){
            is InfoRecyclerViewItems.WithPicture -> R.layout.container_one
            is InfoRecyclerViewItems.WithoutPicture -> R.layout.container_two
        }
    }

}
```

The ViewHolder(s)

```
sealed class MainViewHolder(binding: ViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    class WithPictureViewHolder(private val binding: ContainerOneBinding) : MainViewHolder(binding){
        fun bind(items: InfoRecyclerViewItems.WithPicture){
            binding.part1 = items
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    class WithoutPictureViewHolder(private val binding: ContainerTwoBinding) : MainViewHolder(binding){
        fun bind(items: InfoRecyclerViewItems.WithoutPicture){
            binding.part2 = items
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

}
```

Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)



        binding.recyclerView.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcomed, Thank You.

Comment: View binding or data binding? In my opinion trying to use data binding with RecyclerView is just masochism.

Answer (score 0):

SO I figured it out. based on this setup, I can create an empty MutableList and then call each different data class that I want to fill in. those data classes are linked to the ViewHolder that it is associated to, thus creating two different views inside the RecylerView.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var manager: LinearLayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val information: MutableList<InfoRecyclerViewItems> = ArrayList()
        information.add(InfoRecyclerViewItems.WithPicture(2, "The Fallen", "ok"))
        information.add(InfoRecyclerViewItems.WithoutPicture(4, "Black Panther", "10/10, Fantastic Movie"))

        manager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

       binding.recyclerView.apply {
           adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(information)
           layoutManager = manager
       }

    }
}
```

Then you can just keep adding to whatever view you chose to add it to

P.S. The other files(ViewHolder, Adapter and Data Class) stay the same.